# How can you move the thrust reverser to another part of the airplane?

Tags: landing, thrust-reverser, spoilers

So this is what we need to research simply: Is there a way we can remove the thrust reverser from the airplane and have something else take care of it?

My initial thought was maybe we could put spoilers somewhere to have the same thrust reverser impact but without the actual thrust reversers. What do you guys think?

Comment: You talking about jet engines or prop beta?

Comment: I think you should look at the [airbrakes on a Bae 146](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_brake_(aeronautics)#/media/File%3AEurowings_bae146-300_d-aewb_arp.jpg)

Comment: @Jim so I’m talking about passenger commercial planes like A320

Comment: Aside from everything else, I'm curious what advantage your professor thinks will be gained by moving weight from one part of the plane to another.

Comment: One approach has been it use thrust attenuators, such as Cessna uses on several Citation CJ light jet models.  It's a very simplified paddle that extends out to divert the jet exhaust outward at almost 90 degrees, creating no forward thrust.  The idea is that it is much lighter and mechanically simpler than a true reverser, and can be used on a broader range of runway surfaces or weather conditions.

Comment: Well, not to state the obvious, but (actually, yes to state the obvious), you could always consider retro-rockets!

Comment: (Which could be mounted just about anywhere, especially if hey were arranged in pairs, with one cancelling any yaw, roll, or pitch torque that would be created by the other)

Comment: @quietflyer [those](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bA3TXZ1G2tE) thrusting forward would be an amazing landing to watch

Comment: @quiet flyer Natalya approves

Comment: @quietflyer The forward retro-rockets have been tried, in preparation for an Iranian hostage rescue attempt, and some of the testing failed *spectacularly.*  https://youtu.be/IxEjrMWNwlc

Comment: If your question is in the title (moving reverser to a different part of airplane), then ducting exhaust. If you question is in the description (a way we can remove the trust reverser from the airplane and have something else take care of it), then: aircraft carriers have arresting gear and I imagine there are plenty of other creative ways to slow down an aircraft on/after landing (headwind generator, moving runway). You could also have plethora of different devices on the airplane that would work as reversers and would be mostly inefficient (having no use when they're not used as reversers).

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan - like the [Blackburn Buccaneer](https://www.airliners.net/photo/UK-Air-Force/Blackburn-Buccaneer-S1/881617), and, arguably, the [Space Shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_brake_(aeronautics)#/media/File:STS-116_landing_port_behind.jpg)

Comment: "What do you guys think?" is explicitly asking for opinion and dialog, both of which are off-topic. VtC.

Answer (score 26):

It sounds like your professor doesn't know much about the mechanics of thrust reversers. They are attached to the exhaust end or to a fan shroud extension of an engine because that's where the air flow is that we wish to reverse in the first place. In this sense you can't move the reversers off the engine unless you duct the engine exhaust to where you put the reversers.

*Drag generators* in the form of *speedbrakes* could be placed in, for example, the tail but to match the braking force generated by a thrust reverser the speedbrakes would need to be big.

Note also that as the plane slows down, the speedbrakes lose their effectiveness whereas the thrust reversers do not- they generate braking force as long as the reverser is deployed and the engine is spooled up.

Comment: "It sounds like your professor doesn't know much about the mechanics of thrust reversers. " - Or possibly, this is a thought experiment by the professor, to demonstrate that not every idea is a good idea. And to get the students to show the many ways this is a bad idea.

Comment: The KC-135's have engines without thrust reversers, even though other aircraft with the same motors have them. Apparently the USAF thought the weight savings were more important than the stopping capability. (Like how they can't run an air conditioning pack on the ground... made sense I guess when nobody conceived of the possibility that they'd ever have to operate in middle eastern deserts.)

Comment: @nielsnielsen: I'd also add that use of thrust reversers is actually forbidden in many airports at nighttime and that FARs don't even require them to be used during braking phase: a jetliner must be stopped only by brakes and at some 85% of its MTOW. So thrust reverser are just a nice to have feature

Comment: @RalphJ the A380s outer engines dont have thrust reversers either - and the myth goes (saying its a myth because cant be bothered to go find a source,  but I know its more than a myth) that Airbus wanted no thrust reversers at all but was overruled by the certifying auhority.

Answer (score 7):

You can't really move the thrust reversers to another part of the airplane (they have to be in the airstream of the engine in order to have any thrust to reverse,) but you certainly can have their function replaced by other parts of the aircraft. Some possibilities that are already used by various aircraft:

- Wheel brakes - Almost all airplanes have these already and they're usually the primary way to slow down on the ground.
- Flaps and spoilers - These don't reverse any thrust, but they create a lot of extra aerodynamic drag at high speeds.
- Negative blade pitch - This mostly applies to propeller-driven aircraft, where the blades can be pitched to blow air forwards rather than backwards. Theoretically, one might be able to design the outboard parts of the blades on turbofan jet engines to flip to negative pitch, but this would be insanely hard to do, since airflow in the normal direction must be maintained through the engine core for the engine to run at all. Much easier to just throw thrust reversers in the bypass ducts on turbofans, but turboprops can (and do) have the ability to adjust their props to negative pitch for reverse thrust.
- Parachutes - Some (usually very fast) airplanes deploy parachutes after landing for dramatically increased aerodynamic drag. An extreme example is the Space Shuttle.
- Arresting wires - This is how airplanes stop on aircraft carriers. There's a (really strong) hook on the airplane that catches a (really strong) wire on the deck. Pulling against the wire stops the airplane very quickly.
- Rocket motors (facing backwards) - This is not an especially normal way for airplanes to land, but it [has been done in flight testing by the U.S. Air Force on a modified C-130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Credible_Sport). It was designed to be able to land and take off again using rocket power inside of a sports stadium during the Iran hostage crisis.

There are also some ways that aren't used by current aircraft (usually for very good reasons,) but which could be. For example:

- [Firing a large machine gun](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/) - The [GAU-8 Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAU-8_Avenger) is the autocannon mounted on the U.S. [A-10 Thunderbolt II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Republic_A-10_Thunderbolt_II). Firing it produces approximately 5 tons of recoil force. This is actually more force than what is produced by each engine on the A-10. However, anything in front of the aircraft while said cannon is firing will have a really bad day. Blowing up your own base is usually considered bad form, so A-10s generally don't fire their autocannon while landing.

Comment: "Sir, I have some good news and bad news"...

Comment: :-D  well if you have to land in an enemy's airport it might be a good solution

Answer (score 6):

Another method to move thrust reversers somewhere else is by having a variable pitch fan that pitches down to negative AoA to produce reverse thrust.

According to this wikipedia about [Variable pitch fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_pitch_fan)

> No production engine uses such a feature; however, it will likely be
> required on at least some of the next generation of high bypass ratio
> turbofans.
>
> One advantage of the variable fan option is that varying the fan pitch
> offers the possibility of reversing engine thrust without the need for
> heavy blocker doors, cascades, etc.

[Turbomeca Astafan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbomeca_Astafan) has been tested in flight but not produced

[Rolls-Royce's Ultrafan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent#UltraFan) could be ready for service from 2025

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reverse the thrust, your hypothetical solution could do something to reduce the thrust.

Perhaps mechanically opening a valve into the combustion area to make the burn less effective quickly by lowering pressure at the critical point, or bleeding off the incoming air from the front intake so it starves the combustion and reduces thrust.   Slats in front of the intake could partially or wholly block the incoming air.

Downside, both would be pretty dirty, promoting incomplete combustion and could jeopardise the plane's ability to power-up and go around so would likely never be approved.

Comment: For a completely ridiculous solution suitable only for classwork as a thought-experiment, investigate if flipping the whole engine pod end for end in the wing would produce any positive benefits.  I'd doubt it, but the list of failure modes alone would be many pages let along the engineering challenges.

Comment: can the osprey pivot to fly backwards?

Comment: Engine are already in idle during landing phase i.e. not producing any thrust. Less than idle there's only shutdown ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to the already given answers and just because the original question stated that it was thought as a weight-saving measure for jetliners:

use of thrust reversers is actually forbidden in many airports at nighttime and FARs don't even require them to be used during [braking phase for certification](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qc_v6tXsv6g): a jetliner must be able to stop only using brakes up to some 85% of its MTOW. So thrust reverser are just a nice to have feature.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you say that some places forbid use of thrust reversers at night, do you mean they forbid spooling up the engine with the reversers deployed or that they actually entirely forbid deploying the reversers? They create quite a lot of drag (especially on today's huge turbofans) even if you select them at idle thrust.

Comment: @reirab: yes right, spooling them up due to noise restrictions, thanks for pointing that out